# .find is not a function on cheerio object

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

```
  let playersCell = `
    <td class="foo" colspan="2">
      <a href="example.com">
        <span class="bold">John Beluga</span>
         - Sarah Jay.
       </a>
    </td>
    `

let players = cheerio.load(playersCell)
players.find('a').html()
```

I try to load a html string into cheerio.js and find an `a` tag, but I am getting

> [TypeError: players.find is not a function]

`Console.log` shows for `players`

[image]

Comment: Can you try this `let players = cheerio.load(playersCell);
players('.foo').find('a').html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is a method that appears on DOM search results. You need to create a result before you can use find.

For example:

```js
let playersCell = `<table><tr>
    <td class="foo" colspan="2">
      <a href="example.com">
        <span class="bold">John Beluga</span>
         - Sarah Jay.
       </a>
    </td></tr></table>
    `

let players = cheerio.load(playersCell);
console.log(players('td').find('a').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/cheerio@latest"></script>
```

But in this case, there is no need to. You can just use the initial search directly:

```js
let playersCell = `
    <td class="foo" colspan="2">
      <a href="example.com">
        <span class="bold">John Beluga</span>
         - Sarah Jay.
       </a>
    </td>
    `

let players = cheerio.load(playersCell);
console.log(players('a').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/cheerio@latest"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I got `.find is not a function`, and when I looked at the object in the console that I was trying to find, it said its type was `tag`. I realized I needed to wrap the object again.

```
let results = $('.your .query')
results.each((i, r) => {
  $(r).find('.your .next .query')
})
```